# Product with the url_key attribute already exists when update product image using API

Tags: product-images, ee-1.14.1, soap-api-v1

I want to update product image label for specific store view using API v1.
First, I've created product

```
$res = $client->call($session, 'catalog_product.create', array(
'downloadable',
47,
'standardapiv1_' . uniqid(),
array(
    'websites' => array(2),
    'name' => 'Standard api v1',
    'description' => 'Product description',
    'short_description' => 'Product short description',
    'weight' => '10',
    'status' => '1',
    'visibility' => '4',
    'price' => '100',
    'tax_class_id' => 1,
    'meta_title' => 'Product meta title',
    'meta_keyword' => 'Product meta keyword',
    'meta_description' => 'Product meta description'
),));
```

and added product image to this product

```
$res2 = $client->call($session, 'product_media.create', array(
    $res, array(
        'file' =>$newFile,
        'label'=>'standard api',
        'types'=>array('thumbnail'),
        'exclude'=>0
    )
));
```

Product was successfully created. 
When I run this request to API

```
$res =$client->call($session, 'product_media.update', array(
1047,
'/i/m/image_10.jpg',
array(
    'file'=>$newFile,
    'label'=>'update lbl',
),
'2'));
```

I got this error `Product with the 'standard-api-v1' url_key attribute already exists`.
If last parameter is not set - storeView - everything works well, so source of problem is looks like be here:
`\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Media\Api.php` line 256:

```
try {
    $product->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('not_updated', $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Does anyone know, what am I doing wrong?
I've made some research, and found answers, that it was a bug in EE 1.13

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick. I didn't pass in the store id but you can pass it in the same way that you were.

```
$attrSetId = 4;
$sku       = 'standardapiv1_' . uniqid();

$client    = new SoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1));
$sessionId = $client->login($username, $password);
$productId = $client->call($sessionId, 'catalog_product.create',
                           array('downloadable',
                                 $attrSetId,
                                 $sku,
                                 array(
                                     'websites'          => array(2),
                                     'name'              => 'Standard api v1',
                                     'description'       => 'Product description',
                                     'short_description' => 'Product short description',
                                     'weight'            => '10',
                                     'status'            => '1',
                                     'visibility'        => '4',
                                     'price'             => '100',
                                     'tax_class_id'      => 1,
                                     'meta_title'        => 'Product meta title',
                                     'meta_keyword'      => 'Product meta keyword',
                                     'meta_description'  => 'Product meta description'
                                 ),));

$file        = pathinfo('media/wysiwyg/about-us2.jpg');
$fileContent = base64_encode(file_get_contents($filePath));
$mimeType    = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($filePath));
$attrCodes   = array('small_image', 'base_image', 'thumbnail');

$pathToImg = $client->call($sessionId, 'product_attribute_media.create',
                           array($productId,
                                 array(
                                     'file'     => array(
                                         'name'    => $file['filename'],
                                         'content' => $fileContent,
                                         'mime'    => $mimeType
                                     ),
                                     'label'    => 'Some Image',
                                     'position' => 2,
                                     'types'    => $attrCodes,
                                     'exclude'  => 0
                                 )
                           ));

$result = $client->call($sessionId, 'product_attribute_media.update',
                        array($productId,
                              $pathToImg,
                              array(
                                  'label'    => 'Updated Image Label',
                                  'position' => 2,
                                  'types'    => $attrCodes,
                                  'exclude'  => 0
                              )
                        )
);
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but that is the problem - when @storeView is not passed, everything is OK, error occurs when IT IS passed.

Comment: ok, i will see if i can revamp my answer